# Cómo agregar una condición if dentro de CreateTextNode

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual, studio

Tengo el siguiente código para crear un request en XML con la propiedad XML Document.

```
        //      FlagVinculante
        XmlNode subnodoFlagVinculante = docXml.CreateElement("FlagVinculante");
        subnodoFlagVinculante.AppendChild(docXml.CreateTextNode(vacio));
        nodoDatosSolicitud.AppendChild(subnodoFlagVinculante);

        //      FlagProspector
        XmlNode subnodoFlagProspector = docXml.CreateElement("FlagProspector");
        subnodoFlagProspector.AppendChild(docXml.CreateTextNode(vacio));
        nodoDatosSolicitud.AppendChild(subnodoFlagProspector);

        //      FlagEvaluacionMasiva
        XmlNode subnodoFlagEvaluacionMasiva = docXml.CreateElement("FlagEvaluacionMasiva");
        subnodoFlagEvaluacionMasiva.AppendChild(docXml.CreateTextNode(Solicitud.flagEvaluacionMasiva.ToString()));
        nodoDatosSolicitud.AppendChild(subnodoFlagEvaluacionMasiva);
```

Lo que he tratado de hacer es integrar una condición IF dentro de la propiedad **CreateTextNode()** algo similar a esto:

```
        //      FlagEvaluacionMasiva
        XmlNode subnodoFlagEvaluacionMasiva = docXml.CreateElement("FlagEvaluacionMasiva");
        subnodoFlagEvaluacionMasiva.AppendChild(docXml.CreateTextNode( if (Solicitud.flagEvaluacionMasiva.ToString() == null) { return vacio; } else { (Solicitud.flagEvaluacionMasiva.ToString(); }));
        nodoDatosSolicitud.AppendChild(subnodoFlagEvaluacionMasiva);
```

Existe alguna forma de hacerlo de la manera que espero?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que puedes utilizar el operador [?? - null coalesce](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator): `(Solicitud.flagEvaluacionMasiva.ToString() ?? vacio)`. La documentación explica que devolverá el valor del operando de lado izquierdo en caso de ser diferente de null, de lo contrario, evaluará el operando derecho y devolverá su valor.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó perfectamente.

Comment: Una pregunta. Los nodos **deben** ir ahí aunque tengan valor vacío?. Es decir, `<FlagEvaluacionMasiva>` debe estar presente siempre, aunque no tenga valor?

Comment: Hola, en mi caso si porque en algún momento futuro se utilizará ese nodo, por ello si no se tienen datos recibidos le adjunto una variable string vacía para que al crearse el XML se vaya vacío